# Printing a stack trace from another thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stack-trace

I know I can get the stack trace of the current thread using backtrace() or [NSThread callStackSymbols], but how would I get at the stack trace of a DIFFERENT thread (assuming it's been frozen)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: My original answer will not print from an arbitrary thread. I've since written a proper implementation in my crash handler project: https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash

Specifically, these files:

- https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/blob/master/KSCrash/KSCrash/Reporting/Tools/KSBacktrace.h
- https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/blob/master/KSCrash/KSCrash/Reporting/Tools/KSBacktrace.c

With some help from:

- https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/blob/master/KSCrash/KSCrash/Reporting/Tools/KSMach.h
- https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/blob/master/KSCrash/KSCrash/Reporting/Tools/KSMach.c

What you do is:

- Make a new machine context structure (_STRUCT_MCONTEXT)
- Fill in its stack state using thread_get_state()
- Get the program counter (first stack trace entry) and frame pointer (all the rest)
- Step through the stack frame pointed to by the frame pointer and store all instruction addresses in a buffer for later use.

Note that you should pause the thread before doing this or else you can get unpredictable results.

The stack frame is filled with structures containing two pointers:

- Pointer to the next level up on the stack
- instruction address

So you need to take that into account when walking the frame to fill out your stack trace. There's also the possibility of a corrupted stack, leading to a bad pointer, which will crash your program. You can get around this by copying memory using vm_read_overwrite(), which first asks the kernel if it has access to the memory, so it doesn't crash.

Once you have the stack trace, you can just call backtrace() on it like normal (The crash handler has to be async-safe so it implements its own backtrace method, but in normal cases backtrace() is fine).

Comment: Note that you should suspend the thread while you are reading its stack.

Comment: Also, are you sure this works? It uses `__builtin_frame_address` which is always about the **current** thread.

Comment: So it turns out this doesn't actually work (it does print a stack trace, but I didn't realize it was printing from the current thread). I have some new code that does work as intended, but it's not ready for release yet. I'll post an update once it's ready.

Comment: Hi! Any news on this subject? Thanks.

Comment: The files doesnt seem to exist in later versions of the repo. Im trying to achieve something similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298259/warning-when-blocking-main-thread). Can I use your framework as is for that?

Answer (score 5):

Here is some safer way to get the callstack from another thread: [Implementation](https://github.com/albertz/openlierox/blob/0.59/src/common/Debug_GetCallstack.cpp) and [some background information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049967/133374). It uses signal handling and spawns a signal handler in the target thread. It has also the advantage that it is more cross-platform than your solution, i.e. it should work anywhere where you have `<signal.h>` and `<execinfo.h>`.

For the printing, you can use `backtrace_symbols` as you do in your own suggestion. But you might be interested in an extended version of that as implemented [here](https://github.com/albertz/openlierox/blob/0.59/src/common/Debug_extended_backtrace.cpp). It uses libbfd (from [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/); the recent version also mostly works on MacOSX, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044697/where-how-does-apples-gcc-store-dwarf-inside-an-executable) for a small limitation which might not be relevant for you) to read the debugging information and to add line-number and other information (it also falls back to `dladdr` if all else fails; that is what `backtrace_symbols` is doing).

Comment: I am doing much the same, but was using pthread_sigqueue to pass the context in on linux, but then found that API is not available on macos when I needed to port to that, so was wondering how to get around that. I see you have the context data as globals, protected by a global mutex. I was kind of stuck since you can't safely use a lock in the signal handler, so was looking at lockless queues and so on. Putting the lock in the caller is a good idea.