# Handle iOS Exceptions own way besides Crittercism

Tags: ios, exception, crittercism

I have an ios app in which I am already using Crittercism. It reports the exceptions perfectly.

My problem is that I also want those exceptions to be logged to my backend server.

I have tried a lot of things to make it happen but to no avail.
Here are the list of things I tried:

- Call
  `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);`

If I do this, the exception is not reported in Crittercism.

- Call
  `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);`

Send the exception to my server.
Then call the constructor of Crittercism in `myExceptionHandler` function and rethrow the exception. Doesn't work.

- Call the constructor of Crittercism followed by `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);` and in `myExceptionHandler` call `[Crittercism logHandledException:exception];`. Doesn't work either.
- In my exception handler serialize the exception object and store it in user preferences. When the user restarts the app, call `[Crittercism logHandledException:exception];` and then send the exception to my backend server. Problem with this was, I was not able to deserialize the string to exception object. I couldn't put the stack trace in `NSString` form into my exception object.

Some things I could have tried:

- Let the crittercism handle the exception and then on next restart, `crittercismDidCrashOnLastLoad` will be called - but do I have the exception info present or can I access it from somewhere.
- I may not need to deserialize the string to exception object. I believe Crittercism is also changing the exception into a json object and sending this json object to its servers. But I am not able to find out which functions to use to send a custom json object to crittercism.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this. Firstly init the crittercism object using

```
[Crittercism initWithAppID:crittercismAppID andKey:crittercismKey andSecret:crittercismSecret];
```

Now define

```
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler* crittercismHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();//You have stored the reference to the crittercism function that was going to get called in the event of an exception
```

Then,

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myHandledException);//Set the handler to your custom function
```

In your custom function, do whatever you want to do with your exception and then call

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(crittercismHandler);//this will re-set the exception handler to the one of crittercism
```

Call

```
crittercismHandler(exception);//This will send the exception to crittercism servers.
```

You can do similar things for signals.

Answer (score 1):

You could manage your own exception handling as we do. This page has a link to a sample project
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

and this is also helpful
[Printing a stack trace from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765158/printing-a-stack-trace-from-another-thread)